# Is there a way to group by elements in collection by model?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

Is there a way to group by data in Laravel collection by model?

Example:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1743 ▼
  #items: array:5 [▼
    0 => App\Models\Inicijativa {#1789 ▶}
    1 => App\Models\Obavestenje {#1742 ▶}
    2 => App\Models\Obavestenje {#1733 ▶}
    3 => App\Models\Samoprocena {#1672 ▶}
    4 => App\Models\Samoprocena {#1795 ▶}
  ]
}
```

In this example i want to have 3 groups:

1. Inicijativa with 1 item
2. Obavestenje with 2 items
3. Samoprocena with 2 items

They don't have a column by which i can differentiate them.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a collection you can use whatever you want to group it:

```
$grouped = $collection->groupBy(function ($item) { return get_class($item); });
```

This will group the elements of the collection based on the result of applying [`get_class`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) on each of them. This is allowed since the result of `get_class` is a string indicating the fully qualified name of the object's class